# how to set exact scene rect in QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, graphics

I have problem with QGraphicsView, I don't know how to set the exact viewport for QGraphicsView. for example I wrote following code:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
QGraphicsEllipseItem * ellipse;
QPen pen(Qt::red);
QBrush brush(Qt::blue);
ellipse = scene->addEllipse(10,10,100,100,pen, brush);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
ui->graphicsView->setSceneRect(10,10,100,100);
```

I though that the result must be a circle inside view recangle which its diameter equals to viewport's height or width.
but when I run the program, It shows me a medium sized circle inside view which means that graphicView's sceneRect is larger that I have specified. any body knows why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution by myself:
assume that exactRect is the Exact rectangle you want to zoom into:

```
QRectF exactRect(20, 10, 300, 200);
ui->graphicsView->setSceneRect(exactRect);
ui->graphicsView->setCenterOn(exactRect.center());
QMatrix mtx;
mtx.scale(ui->graphicsView->width()/exactRect.width(),
          ui->graphicsView->height()/exactRect.height());
ui->graphicsView->setMatrix(mtx);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `fitInView()`:

```
// when graphicsView is visible:
ui->graphicsView->fitInView(ui->graphicsView->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

Comment: Mybe I coudn't explain the problem well. all I what to tell is that when I use setSceneRect(....) the final sceneRect of GraphicsView is not what I expected.

Comment: How do you know that the view is larger than you specified? What does `ui->graphicsView->sceneRect();` says? Post screenshots of what you expect and what you get.

Comment: It says that the rectangle is exactly what I would like to be, but what I see is that the real viewport is bigger that sceneRect()

Comment: Like I said, layout has a higher priority than scene rectangle size.

Comment: I think that I totally misunderstood sth. I though that when I specify a rectangle, the GraphicsView widget shows exactly that rectangle, so It would automatically zoom and translate the scene to cover the exact are. I think I was wrong, What I am going to believe is that the GraphicsView has nothing to do with zooming the scene and It just translates the scene. so what can I do to show the exact rectangle of scene inside the GraphicsView?

Comment: I think you want `fitInView()`.